# Is there a way to make the json.load() function not produce an error if there's an extra command in a json file?

Tags: python, json

I'm making a small program to help me and possibly other people with managing projects, and I got this problem:

The program works like this, you can add projects, with a name and description, and you can add tasks that you can assign to the projects, and mark them as done when you do it, I use a .json file to store this data, because it seems easier and not complicated, and can be customized easily if someone wants to edit it manually. This is the code to make the file:

```py
def load():
    try:
        file = open(filePath, 'r+')
        return json.load(file)
    except:
        create = open(filePath, 'w+')

        toWrite = {
            "projects": []
        }

        json.dump(toWrite, create)
        create.close()

        file = open(filePath, 'r+')
        return json.load(file)
```

This basically creates the file if it doesn't exist, but the problem is that if the user manually puts an extra comma in the .json file, it will result in an error and therefore the file will be deleted. Here is an example:

```json
{
    "projects": [
        {
            "name": "example project",
            "description": "",
            "tasks": []
        }, <----
    ]
}
```

If that comma next to the arrow is there (*doesn't necessarily have to be at the same position, it can be after the tasks array and it will still result in an error*), the error will occur. This is what the file looks like after it resets:

```json
{"projects": []}
```

I'm wondering if there is a way to avoid/make this not count as an error. Thanks.

Comment: That isn't valid JSON. If you let people edit the file directly, they can screw it up. Either don't let them, or make it clear that doing so can result in data loss. There isn't really anything else to do here.

Comment: You should only create a new file in case of a `FileNotFoundError`, not any exception type whatsoever.

Comment: @JaredSmith Do you mean invaild JSON that JSON can't have an extra comma/doesn't support it?

Comment: That is not valid JSON, JSON does not allow trailing commas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was fixed thanks to a comment by jasonharper. Basically what I needed to do is use FileNotFoundError for the exception, this won't avoid the problem but will avoid the file being lost. Apparently there JSON doesn't allow trailing commas.